# offset class not applied into a bootstrap 2 form

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

should be an easy one.

Why does the offsetX class not work on the 2 last divs?

```
<form class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
            <div class="controls  ">
                <input class="span12" type="text" placeholder=".span12">
            </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row ">
                <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4"> 
                <input class="span8" type="text" placeholder=".span8">
            </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row ">
                <input class="span9" type="text" placeholder=".span9"> 
                <input class="span3" type="text" placeholder=".span3">
            </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row ">
                <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6"> 
                <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6">
            </div>
                        <div class="controls controls-row ">
                <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4"> 
                <input class="span6 offset2" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
            </div>
                                    <div class="controls controls-row ">
                <input class="span4 offset2" type="text" placeholder=".span4 offset2"> 
                <input class="span6 " type="text" placeholder=".span6 ">
            </div>
        </form>
```

can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/b0zqnmbL/

Comment: try wrapping all your inputs in a div having class row-fluid. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: Because offsets are removed from any `input` with a `span*` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant at all, but so far I get better results than Megh Vidani and Manoj Kumar's solutions:

```
...
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
    <label class="span2"   ></label>
    <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
</div>
...
```

Ugly but 100% efficient.
All feel free to post more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the `offset-*` classes to the parent since offset with input span elements is being overridden by the Bootstrap rule below.

`input[class*="span"] { margin-left: 0; }`

Since you need to retain the control classes and also in the same line, I have modified the markup and also added a media query.

**Modified code:**

```
<div class="controls controls-row ">
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row offset2">
    <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row offset2">
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4 offset2">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row ">
    <input class="span6 " type="text" placeholder=".span6 ">
</div>

@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .controls-row {
     display: inline-block;
   }
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brw2g2b5/1/)

Comment: But in your updated fiddle, the offseted inputs are displayed on a new line.

I want them to be displaed on the same line as on the 2 previous lines.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oh, I just changed the screen size to see the problem. Let me fix it.

Comment: Do you want to retain the control classes?

Comment: yep, to make it more challenging for you hehe :)

Comment: Just modified the code a bit more for the "challenge" ;)

Comment: I can see it work on JSFiddle, but if I ad your @media bloc into my bs.css file and test, it does not behave correctly.

The ".span4 offset2" input is displayed in a new line.
I suppose this is because of this part: min-width: 768px ?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<div class="offset2">
  <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
</div>
```

instead of

```
<input class="span6 offset2" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
```

**UPDATE:**

It's behaving funny.
I got it working by the following code:
I know It's not the exact answer but if you can get away with it meanwhile ;)

```
<form class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
<div class="controls  ">
    <input class="span12" type="text" placeholder=".span12">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row ">
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
    <input class="span8" type="text" placeholder=".span8">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row ">
    <input class="span9" type="text" placeholder=".span9">
    <input class="span3" type="text" placeholder=".span3">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row ">
    <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6">
    <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
<input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
    <div class="span2" ></div>
    <div class="offset2">
        <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="offset2">
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4 offset2">
        </div>
    <input class="span6 " type="text" placeholder=".span6 ">
</div>
</form>
```

Or I would suggest an alternative if you're not very much strict on using `offset2` only:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4">
    <div class="span2" ></div>
    <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4 offset2">
    <input class="span6 " type="text" placeholder=".span6 ">
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="controls controls-row ">
                <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4"> 
                 <div class="offset2">
                       <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6 offset2">
                 </div>
            </div>

still does not work (I want the 2 inputs on the same line)

Comment: This one nearly works. "Nearly" because the ".span4 offset2" input is not completely aligned where it should.
I have found a non elegent way to have it all correctly alligned. I ll post it now as an answer.

Comment: hey, I don't know how but adding `row` class to `<div class="controls controls-row">` in your newly posted answer aligns the controls in the last row perfectly. Don't need to add it in the second last row. Still code is ugly and quite weird! ;)
Don't have enough reputation so can't post it as a comment to your answer! :/